# Connect to external monitor using HDMI

Tags: vga, hdmi

I want to connect my laptop to external monitor, but it doesn't have VGA socket. It only has HDMI.

I recently purchased a HDMI to VGA cable and tried with it, but still it doesn't recognize the input.
I checked on the internet and found that I need to use HDMI to VGA Adapter and not just the cable with two different plugs.

So is it true or is there any way to use the cable which I have already purchased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true and there isn't any useful way to use the cable you have bought. In fact, many of these HDMI-VGA cables are actually completely useless as there are virtually no devices that output any useful VGA signals via the HDMI port.

You would need to purchase a proper adapter which has what is essentially a separate video card in it (something like [this](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/products/7781882/)). I use a similar device with my own laptop which converts the digital DisplayPort data into Analog VGA signals.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I will get same type of adaptor as you mentioned.